# Importing modal.less in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to import modals.less file in my project, using bootstrap(v3.3.7)

Below is the bootstrap.less code:

```
 /*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * Custom file
 */

 // Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";


// Core CSS
@import "scaffolding.less";
@import "grid.less";
@import "forms.less";
@import "buttons.less";

// Components
@import "modals.less";
@import "navs.less";
@import "dropdowns.less";
@import "popovers.less";


// Utility classes
@import "utilities.less";
@import "responsive-utilities.less";
```

But it's throwing an error while importing

> message: '.transition-transform is undefined

which is this line:

```
// When fading in the modal, animate it to slide down
  &.fade .modal-dialog {
    .translate(0, -25%);
    .transition-transform(~"0.3s ease-out");
  }
```

Do I need to also import any other dependencies that I am not aware of to use modal?

**Edit**:

```
// Mixins
// --------------------------------------------------



// Utilities
@import "mixins/tab-focus.less";
@import "mixins/hide-text.less";
@import "mixins/responsive-visibility.less";
@import "mixins/image.less";
@import "mixins/reset-filter.less";
@import "mixins/reset-text.less";
/*
@import "mixins/opacity.less";
@import "mixins/labels.less";
@import "mixins/resize.less";
@import "mixins/size.less";
@import "mixins/vendor-prefixes.less";
@import "mixins/text-emphasis.less";
@import "mixins/text-overflow.less";*/

// Components
@import "mixins/forms.less";
@import "mixins/buttons.less";
@import "mixins/nav-divider.less";
/*
@import "mixins/alerts.less";
@import "mixins/panels.less";
@import "mixins/pagination.less";
@import "mixins/list-group.less";

@import "mixins/progress-bar.less";
@import "mixins/table-row.less";*/

// Skins
@import "mixins/border-radius.less";
/*
@import "mixins/background-variant.less";
@import "mixins/gradients.less";
*/
// Layout
@import "mixins/clearfix.less";
@import "mixins/center-block.less";
@import "mixins/nav-vertical-align.less";
@import "mixins/grid-framework.less";
@import "mixins/grid.less";
```

Comment: does your `mixins.less` have the line `@import "mixins/vendor-prefixes.less";`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I just checked and there is no `vendor-prefixes.less` file in mixins folder. **Negative**

Comment: But you are running `v3.3.7`? It should be there: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less

Comment: I'm using it in a customized way, so not using all of the files together.

Comment: Then I recommend that you add that one file to the mixins folder and add `@import "mixins/vendor-prefixes.less";`.  normally it appears under the `// Utilities` comment in [mixins.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/less/mixins.less)

Comment: If it throws another error, you can either resolve those errors by adding in the needed files or just trimming down the `vendor-prefixes.less` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation via the comments above, it seems the issue was that `@import "mixins/vendor-prefixes.less";` was commented out in the `mixins.less` file.  I recommend uncommenting that line.

Comment: It's working now, I see all the transition and other rules are defined in that less file.